# jquery not acting as I expect it to

Tags: jquery, css, form-submit

There seems to be an issue with something that I am trying to do in regards to check boxes (or radio boxes) and showing hidden content.

### **Html**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="carousel" class="carouselGlobal" name="aisis_options[carousel_global]" value="carousel_global">
```

Simple check box. Now lets add some jquery to display a hidden section, with the div class of `.sectionCarousel`

### **jQuery**

```
    $('.carouselGlobal').click(function(){
        if ($(this).attr("id") == "carousel"){
            $('.sectionCarousel').show();
        } else {
            $('.sectionCarousel').hide();
        }
    });
```

This is easy, you click, you see, you click off, you don't see.....**wrong**

**Issue**

If I click the check box using the above code to display the hidden section it shows, if I click the check box again to unchecked the item is still there.

So now if we save the form, we assume the check box stays checked on page refresh, we need to keep the section displayed so we do:

### **jQuery**

```
    if ($('input[value=carousel_global]:checkbox:checked').attr('id') === "carousel") {
        $('.sectionCarousel').show();
    }
```

Which is pretty simple in what it does.

Issue number one is repeated here again, if you click the check box to un-check it, the section is still display. How ever if you save the form at this point then the section disappears until you click the check box again.

As you can see that can become an issue.

So I ask you:

**before form save**

When I click the check box the hidden section should display, when I click it again to un-check, it should disappear.

**After form save**

Assuming the check box is clicked on page refresh the section should remain visible, if I then click the check box to unchecked it, the content (in this case the section) should disappear.

Clicking to show works, un-checking and it (the section) disappearing - does not work. Why?

Comment: You should be testing the `checked` state of the checkbox, not testing its `id` - the `id` isn't going to change... Try `if (this.checked) {...`

Comment: Like @nnnnnn said, you need to see if the checkbox is checked when it's clicked. You also need to check to see if the checkbox is checked on page load by using the `.ready()` event within jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must use a click event bound to a group of elements you need to also check the checked state, similar to this:

```
$('.carouselGlobal').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var theId = this.id;

    if (theId === "carousel"){
        if($this.is(":checked")){
            $('.sectionCarousel').show();
        } else {
            $('.sectionCarousel').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/97tx6/) - Adding state check

---

**Edit**

> Your piece of code works until I submit the form, after words the
>   check box is still clicked but the section div is hidden, when it
>   should not be.

You can work around this by separating your code similar to this:

```
var setSectionCarouselState = function (showIt) {
    if (showIt) {
        $('.sectionCarousel').show();
    } else {
        $('.sectionCarousel').hide();
    }
}

$('.carouselGlobal').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var theId = this.id;

    if (theId === "carousel") {
        setSectionCarouselState($this.is(":checked"));
    }
});

setSectionCarouselState($('#carousel').is(":checked"));
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7dgRv/) - Separating the code

---

The code above is not intended for copy-pasting as it works in an isolated environment of a `jsFiddle` but minor tweaks may be required to get it to work within your specific environment.

**Edit**

> if I have 6 or seven of these, obviously different id's and classes is
>   there an easy way to handle them or would I write out something
>   similar to this answer, for each one?

I'm not 100% sure how your setup is, but assuming you have multiple `checkboxes` which each 
show/hide 1-to-1 another element or selector. You can write a more generic solution.

One option would be to use a `data-attribute` approach in which you assign each `checkbox` the selector it suppose to effect. This would make the use of `id` attribute redundant too.

Assume you have HTML similar to this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="carouselGlobal">
<input type="checkbox" class="carouselGlobal" data-target-selector=".anotherSectionCarousel">
<input type="checkbox" class="carouselGlobal" data-target-selector=".sectionCarousel" checked>

<div class="sectionCarousel" style="display:none;">section carousel</div>
<div class="anotherSectionCarousel" style="display:none;">another section carousel</div>
```

As you can see above, each `checkbox` has a `data-target-selector` attribute containing the selector of the element it suppose to effect.

Your script becomes quite small now:

```
// method which takes in the DOM reference of a checkbox
// interrogates the data attribute and uses it
// to show/hide the matching element
var setTargetState = function (checkbox) {
    var $this = $(checkbox);
    var $target = $($this.attr('data-target-selector'));

    if(!$target.length){
        return;
    }

    if ($this.is(":checked")) {
        $target.show();
    } else {
        $target.hide();
    }
}

// click event drastically simplified
$('.carouselGlobal').click(function () {
    setTargetState(this);
});

// iterates through all checkboxes ensureing the initial state is applied
$('.carouselGlobal').each(function(){
    setTargetState(this);
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UxhKR/) - Using a data attribute for example

---

Comment: Your piece of code works until I submit the form, after words the check box is still clicked but the section div is hidden, when it should not be. The only time, after form submission that it should be hidden is when I uncheck the corresponding check box.

Comment: Then move the code inside a function you can then call when you initialize your page and from within the click event as needed. I'll add a possible way of dealing with that but it is a different issue all together.

Comment: I don't see how that's a different issue, the code I have presented in the OP shows what happens before form submission in the first Jquery block and what happens after form submission in the second jquery block. My code works, except for the fact that unclicking the check-boxes does not hide the content when it should. Your code works 90%, its the 10% of "section should remain open" after form submission.

Comment: @TheWebs: I didn't mean different issue as in different question. I'm merely referring to the fact that you have 2 separate issue to deal with. The first was the logic and the second one being the issue of persisting the state of the elements. I will correct my wording to prevent any confusion. I have also added code demonstrating how you can address the issue regarding the form submission.

Comment: My final question, is less of about the issue at hand and more of one about modularity, if I have 6 or seven of these, obviously different id's and classes is there an easy way to handle them or would I write out something similar to this answer, for each one? - thanks for your help.

Comment: @TheWebs: If you have a group of checkboxes but expect each one to show/hide a different element you could apply some generic way of dealing with it using `data` attributes to associate the checkboxes with the elements to show/hide. The checkbox with id `carousel` can for example have a `data-target-selector=".sectionCarousel"` You then don't need an id check but do something similar to this [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/UxhKR//) I also added this to the answer as an example.

Answer (score 1):

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P4yse/)**

Consider using toggle, and using the `id` to target the checkbox, like this:

```
$("#carousel").click(function(){$('.sectionCarousel').toggle();});
```

Comment: this might work for clicking, but what about keeping the section open after form submission and the rest of the OP?

Comment: @TheWebs - This solves the problem listed in the code as stated in your question "If I click the check box using the above code to display the hidden section it shows, if I click the check box again to unchecked the item is still there." Maintaining state after a page refresh is a whole other issue which would include localstorage, a server session, or a database. Please ask a different question and present code if you can reproduce an issue you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#carousel').click(function(){
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
        $('.sectionCarousel').show();
    }else{
        $('.sectionCarousel').hide();
    }
});
```

And you'll want to have this inside your `$(document).ready()` function:

```
if($('#carousel').is(':checked')){
    $('sectionCarousel').show();
else{
    $('sectionCarousel').hide();
}
```

Comment: Seeing OP stated that clicking the checkbox the first time it shows the element but only when clicking it a second time it does not hide it as expected it would be safe to assume document ready is not the issue but the issue is being related to the applied logic within the event.